# Simplify Panels "Add content to" popup with fewer options for end users

Tags: panels

Echoing [this unanswered question](http://groups.drupal.org/node/103189) on D.O.

Is there a way to limit (and possibly reorganize) the Panels content types and panes presented to website editors?

Basically taking it from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

I tried using some of the [cTools API alter hooks](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!ctools!ctools.api.php/7), but no dice.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://drupal.org/project/Panopoly - they make a lot of customizations to this to improve the ui.

Some more details from the project page:

> Panopoly is powerful base distribution of Drupal powered by lots of Chaos Tools and Panels magic. The distribution is designed to be both a general foundation for site building and a base framework upon which to build other Drupal distributions